# Parsing a String to LocalDateTime with optional trailing truncated zeros

Tags: java, string, parsing, datetime-format

The string that is being passed from the API normally follows the format `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS` but when there are trailing 0s in the timestamp they are cut off, for example `2019-07-16 13:29:15.100` is converted to `2019-07-16 13:29:15.1` and `2019-07-16 13:29:15.110` is converted to `2019-07-16 13:29:15.11`. I have a working solution which simply pads the end with zeros, but this feels like the kind of problem that can be solved with optional sections in the DateTimeFormatter String. The closest I have to a working solution is as follows:

```
String toParse = "2019-07-16 13:29:15.111";
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss[.[S[S[S]]]]");
LocalDateTime timestamp = LocalDateTime.parse(toParse, formatter);
```

Which works for all the cases with trailing zeros truncated but not the case shown where all the digits in the milliseconds are nonzero. The error message is

```
java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2019-07-16 13:29:15.111' could not be parsed, unparsed text found at index 21
```

Is this just an issue with bracket placement? I am using Java 8 and we cannot change what is passed by the API.

Comment: I cannot reproduce. I can successfully run your code...

Comment: @Sweeper The code doesn’t give the quite correct result. Expected: `2019-07-16T13:29:15.111`. Observed on my Java 11: `2019-07-16T13:29:15.100`. For an explanation see my answer.

Comment: @OleV.V. Ah... I didn't actually check the parsed result. I was just pointing out that didn't get the mentioned exception. And wow, I didn't know square brackets break up repetition patterns! Learned something new.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not really perfect of these optional brackets for milli seconds, but you can always created  [DateTimeFormatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) with optional milli seconds using  [DateTimeFormatterBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.html)

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter1 = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder().appendPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
                                    .optionalStart()
                                    .appendFraction(ChronoField.MILLI_OF_SECOND, 0, 3, true)
                                    .optionalEnd()
                                    .toFormatter();
```

Comment: This worked! I was trying to be fancy with the brackets but this seems like a much more robust solution.

Answer (score 2):

### Use the built-in parts

Writing your own format pattern string is not only sometimes tricky, it is also always error-prone. I recommend that instead you assemble your formatter from built-in parts:

```
    String toParse = "2019-07-16 13:29:15.111";
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
            .append(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE)
            .appendLiteral(' ')
            .append(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_TIME)
            .toFormatter();
    LocalDateTime timestamp = LocalDateTime.parse(toParse, formatter);

    System.out.println(timestamp);
```

Output:

> 2019-07-16T13:29:15.111

This works with no decimals at all (`2019-07-16 13:29:15`) and everything from one decimal (`2019-07-16 13:29:15.1`) up to nine decimals (`2019-07-16 13:29:15.123456789`). It even works without the seconds (`2019-07-16 13:29`).

If you *want* to throw an exception for 4 or more decimals, you do need to use `appendFraction()` as in the answer by Deadpool.

It’s in the documentation of `DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_TIME`:

> The format consists of:
>
> - Two digits for the hour-of-day. This is pre-padded by zero to ensure two digits.
> - A colon
> - Two digits for the minute-of-hour. This is pre-padded by zero to ensure two digits.
> - If the second-of-minute is not available then the format is complete.
> - A colon
> - Two digits for the second-of-minute. This is pre-padded by zero to ensure two digits.
> - If the nano-of-second is zero or not available then the format is complete.
> - A decimal point
> - One to nine digits for the nano-of-second. As many digits will be output as required.

### Why square brackets didn’t work here

Your can’t put square brackets in the middle of a string of repetitions of the same format pattern letter. `[.[S[S[S]]]]` is understood as optionally a point optionally followed by one-digit fraction of second optionally followed by one-digit fraction of second optionally followed by one-digit fraction of second. As Sweeper noted in a comment, it may run without exception when the fraction is `.111`, but it will probably be understood as `.1` with the `1` being specified three times. And will break if the three digits are not equal. Instead you might have got away with `[.[SSS][SS][S]]` for an optional decimal point followed by either 3, 2 or 1 decimal. You would need to put the 3 decimals first.

### Link

- [Documentation of `DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_TIME`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ISO_LOCAL_TIME)